# Exception handling - how to handle invalid datatype in user input?

Tags: python

Being new to programming, I am trying to input name which is a string input. If I enter anything other than a string, error should be displayed as invalid input type. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Using the `raw_input()` (Python 2) or `input()` (Python 3) functions, the return is always a string, never any other type.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far ? also, what exactly do you mean by "anything other than string" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Get input from user by `raw_input()` (Python 2) or `input()` (Python 3).
2. `Type` of variable `name` is `string`, so we have to use string method to valid user enter string.
3. Use `isalpha()` string method to check user entered string is valid or not.

code:

```
name = raw_input("Enter your Last Name:")
if not name.isalpha():
    print "Enter only alpha values."
```

output:

```
:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 5.py 
Enter your Last Name:vivek
:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 5.py 
Enter your Last Name:123
Enter only alpha values.
:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 5.py 
Enter your Last Name:vivek 123
Enter only alpha values.
```

---

Other string methods to check user string is integer or alpha or both

```
>>> "123".isalnum()
True
>>> "123a".isalnum()
True
>>> "123abc".isalnum()
True
>>> "123abc".isalpha()
False
>>> "123abc".isdigit()
False
>>> "123".isdigit()
True
>>> "123".isalpha()
False
```

---

By Type conversion and Exception method

e.g. for invalid input:

```
>>> a = "123a"
>>> try:
...    a = int(a)
... except ValueError:
...    print "User string is not number"
... 
User string is not number
```

e.g. for valid input:

```
>>> a = "123"
>>> try:
...    a = int(a)
... except ValueError:
...    print "User string is not number"
... 
>>> print a
123
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>>
```

---

Ask user to enter value again and again if user enter invalid value.

code:

```
while 1:
    try:
        age = int(raw_input("what is your age?: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Enter only digit."
        continue

print "age:", age
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 5.py 
what is your age?: test
Enter only digit.
what is your age?: 123test
Enter only digit.
what is your age?: 24
age: 24
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Where can I get these in build functions?? I am also trying for integers.. is there similar function for integer... if not integer display error

Comment: yes, use `isdigit()` string method to check integer value or use `try except` with type conversion.

Comment: I am getting error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit' when I use isdigit() my code is  age = int (input ("Enter age:"))
if not age.isdigit():
    print ("Enter numbers only")

Comment: yes correct, you are converting user input from `string` to `int` i.e. type casting in statement  ` age = int (input ("Enter age:"))` . `isdigit()` is method of string, not integer.  Remove type casting from your code and check. or use exception handling for existing code if user enter any other value then integer .

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried with the try except code, but it is not printing print values. Here is my code... pls check and let me know where I am making mistake in the coding. sorry for bothering I am still learning.. age = int (input ("Enter age:"))
    try:
        age = int (age)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Entered value is not a number")

Comment: we have to use `try except` for type casting i.e for statement `age = int (input ("Enter age:"))` , As `age` type is integer then now need of  ` try: age = int (age) except ValueError: print ("Entered value is not a number") ` statement.
can you send me your code by skype (vivek.igp) or gmail (vivekbsable@gmail.com), so I can explain in more details.

Comment: @Srini : Can you check my answer again I updated again for - Ask user to enter value again and again if user enter invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an if statement like this:

```
if not entry.isalpha():
   print ("Invalid entry!")
```