# Integrating Exception Handling for Data Types

Tags: python, class, validation, exception, functional-programming

**System:** O365

**IDE:** JupyterLab

**Language:** Python version 3.7.3

**Library:** pandas version 1.0.1

**Data source:** personally built

Hello, I am wondering if anyone knows how I can refactor my code to integrate exception handling to create a data validation scheme for an entry form. Essentially I have four variables I need to protect and I am having a hard time trying to figure out should data validation be integrated within the "class-functions (bank.py and client.py)" or within the "source-code (main.py)" itself. The four variables that require validation are:

**Variables Needing Validation:**

1. Name: as a str
2. Address: as a str or validated against some address API for verification if available?
3. Account: as either checking or savings
4. Deposit amount: as a positive float

**Code (input screen):**

[image: exception]

**Code (first class: bank.py):**

class Bank:

```
name = 'Springboard Federal Credit Union'
clients = []

def update_db(self, client):
    """This function updates the internal memory database with clients account information.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    self : is the autogenerated index in the database to house account details.
    client : is the client details from the client file
    
    Returns
    ----------
    Stores account details and returns the account information for indexing later.
    """
    self.clients.append(client)

def authentication(self, name, account_number):
    """This function validates users credentials to allow retrieval of information later.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    name : takes in the full name of the account holder as a str.
    account_number : is the autogenerated random account_number from client.py file
    
    Returns
    ----------
    Stores account details and returns the account information for indexing later.
    """
    for i in range(len(self.clients)):
        if name in self.clients[i].account.values() and account_number in self.clients[i].account.values():
            print()
            print("Authentication successful!")
            print("==========================================")
            return self.clients[i]
```

**Code (second class: client.py):**

```
from random import randint

class Client:

    account = {}

    def __init__(self, name, address, account, deposit):
        """This function instantiates a new account with five parameters: random generated account number, 
        name, address, account, and initial deposit.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        self : is an autogenerated random account_number to instantiate a new account number as a num
        name : takes in the full name of the account holder as a str
        address : takes in the full address of the account holder as a str
        account : takes in the account type: (checking or savings) as a str
        deposit : takes in a num as a float
        
        Returns
        ----------
        Stores account details 
        """
        self.account['account_number'] = randint(10000, 99999)
        self.account['name'] = name
        self.account['address'] = address
        self.account['account type'] = account
        self.account['balance'] = deposit

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """This function decreases balance number by some applied amount.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        amount : new amount to be subtracted from balance
        
        Returns
        ----------
        balance -= amount
        """
        if self.account['balance'] >= amount:
            self.account['balance'] -= amount
            print()
            print("The sum of {} has been withdrawn from your account balance.".format(amount))
            self.balance()
        else:
            print()
            print("Insufficient funds!")
            self.balance()

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """This function increases balance number by some applied amount.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        amount : new amount to be added to balance
        
        Returns
        ----------
        balance += amount
        """        
        self.account['balance'] += amount
        print()
        print("The sum of {} has been added to your account balance.".format(amount))
        self.balance()

    def balance(self):
        """This function presents the balance.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        self.account : the accont number
        
        Returns
        ----------
        The current balance from the stated account
        """
        print()
        print("Your current account balance is: {} ".format(self.account['balance']))
```

**Code (source code: main.py):**

```
## Import files
from client import Client
from bank import Bank

# Setting Bank function to a variable
bank = Bank()

# Spelling out welcome banner
welcome = "Welcome to {}!".format(bank.name)
print(f' --------------------------------------------\n {welcome}\n --------------------------------------------')

# Running input prompt
running = True
while running:
    print()
    print("""Choose an option:
    
    1. Open a new bank account
    2. Access existing bank account
    3. Exit terminal
    """)

    choice = int(input("1, 2 or 3: "))

    # Selected if option 1: Open new bank account is chosen
    try:
        if choice == 1:
            print(f' \nTo create a new account, please provide the information below.\n ')
            client = Client(input("Name: "), str(input("Address: ")), str(input("Account Type (checking or savings): ")), float(input("Deposit amount: ")))
            bank.update_db(client)
            client_account = client.account['account_number']
            print(f'_______________________________________________________________\n<<Account created successfully! Your account number is: {client_account}>>')

        # Selected if option 2: Access existing bank account
        elif choice == 2:
            print(f' \nTo access your account, please enter your access information.\n ')
            name = input("Name: ")
            account_number = int(input("Account number: "))
            current_client = bank.authentication(name, account_number)
            if current_client:
                print()
                print("Welcome {}!".format(current_client.account['name']))
                acc_open = True
                while acc_open:
                    print()
                    print("""Choose an option:

        1. Withdraw
        2. Deposit
        3. Balance
        4. Exit Account Window
                        """)
                    acc_choice = int(input("1, 2, 3 or 4: "))

                    if acc_choice == 1: # Selected if sub-option 1: Withdraw
                        print()
                        current_client.withdraw(int(input("Withdraw amount: ")))
                    elif acc_choice == 2: # Selected if sub-option 2: Deposit
                        print()
                        current_client.deposit(int(input("Deposit amount: ")))
                    elif acc_choice == 3:  # Selected if sub-option 3: Balance
                        print()
                        current_client.balance()
                    elif acc_choice == 4:  # Selected if sub-option 4: Exit Account Window
                        current_client = ''
                        acc_open = False
            else:
                print(f' \n-Authentication failed!\n-Reason: Account not found.\n----\nDo you want to try again? If not, ')
                continue

        # Selected if option 3: Exit the terminal
        elif choice == 3:
            running = False
    
    # If anything breaks within the try statement (i.e. an individual tries to pass in a letter for an account number) run this general exception
    except Exception:
        print('-- We apologize for the inconvenience. --\n-- Due to security reasons suspicious activity has occured and we are terminating this session. --\nPlease try back at a later time.')
    
    # Do this no matter what happens within the program
    finally:
        print(f'==========================================\nThank you for allowing us to service you!\n==========================================')
```

**Problem**

I need to understand a way to integrate exception handling to help validate the entries so not to contaminate my database.

**Steps Taken**

1. I reviewed the following post by Srini at: [Exception handling - how to handle invalid datatype in user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377995/exception-handling-how-to-handle-invalid-datatype-in-user-input)
2. It seems like this is what I need however I am trying to find out should I integrate this into the class functions or should I build it into the: try, except, finally "exception handling" within the main source code above.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated as I have been working on this for a while now. :)

Comment: you should not put an exception in the finally part of your already existing exception, as it is **always** executed (clean up action). The finally block always executes after normal termination of try block or after try block terminates due to some exception - see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html for a short summary.

Comment: @xltc, I am actually trying to find out how to set a data type validation for the entries for checking or savings account. Right now my code allows for anything to be passed into checking and or savings and I want this to be caught if the entry is something other than checking and or savings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the answer below if anyone else gets stuck on this or needs some help similar to this problem's use-case. Big thanks to @xtlc!

**first class**

```
class Bank:

    name = 'Springboard Federal Credit Union'
    clients = []
    valid_account_types= ['checking', 'savings']

    def validate_client(self, client):
        """This function validates the account type and initial deposit entered by the user.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        self : is the autogenerated index in the database to house client details.
        client : is the client details from the client file.
        
        Returns
        ----------
        Returns a printed statement if account is not valid.
        Returns a printed statement if the user tries to pull a balance less than 0.
        """
        account_type = client.account['account_type']
        if (account_type not in self.valid_account_types):
            print("Not a valid account_type")
            return False
        balance = client.account['balance']
        if (balance <= 0.0):
            print("you must have a positive balance to create an account")
            return False
        return True

    def update_db(self, client):
        """This function updates the internal memory database with clients account information.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        self : is the autogenerated index in the database to house account details.
        client : is the client details from the client file.
        
        Returns
        ----------
        Stores account details and returns the account information for indexing later.
        """
        if (self.validate_client(client)):
            self.clients.append(client)
            return True
        else:
            print("can not create account, one or more information are not correct")
            return False

    def authentication(self, name, account_number):
        """This function validates users credentials to allow retrieval of information later.
        
        Parameters  
        ----------
        name : takes in the full name of the account holder as a str.
        account_number : is the autogenerated random account_number from client.py file.
        
        Returns
        ----------
        Stores account details and returns the account information for indexing later.
        """
        for i in range(len(self.clients)):
            client = self.clients[i]
            if (name == client.account['name']) and (account_number == client.account['account_number']):
                print()
                print("Authentication successful!")
                print("==========================================")
                return self.clients[i]
```

**second class**

```
from random import randint

class Client:

    account = {}

    def __init__(self, name, address, account, deposit):
        """This function instantiates a new account with five parameters: random-generated account number, 
        name, address, account, and initial deposit.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        self : is an autogenerated random account_number to instantiate a new account number as a num
        name : takes in the full name of the account holder as a str
        address : takes in the full address of the account holder as a str
        account : takes in the account type: (checking or savings) as a str
        deposit : takes in a num as a float
        
        Returns
        ----------
        Stores account details. 
        """
        self.account['account_number'] = randint(10000, 99999)
        self.account['name'] = name.strip()
        self.account['address'] = address.strip()
        self.account['account_type'] = account.strip()
        self.account['balance'] = deposit

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """This function decreases balance number by some applied amount.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        amount : new amount to be subtracted from balance
        
        Returns
        ----------
        balance -= amount
        """
        if self.account['balance'] >= amount:
            self.account['balance'] -= amount
            print()
            print("The sum of {} has been withdrawn from your account balance.".format(amount))
            self.balance()
        else:
            print()
            print("Insufficient funds!")
            self.balance()

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """This function increases balance number by some applied amount.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        amount : new amount to be added to balance.
        
        Returns
        ----------
        balance += amount
        """        
        self.account['balance'] += amount
        print()
        print("The sum of {} has been added to your account balance.".format(amount))
        self.balance()

    def balance(self):
        """This function presents the balance.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        self.account : the accont number
        
        Returns
        ----------
        The current balance from the stated account
        """
        print()
        print("Your current account balance is: {} ".format(self.account['balance']))
```

**main source-code**

```
## Import files
from client import Client
from bank import Bank

# Setting Bank function to a variable
bank = Bank()

# Spelling out welcome banner
welcome = "Welcome to {}!".format(bank.name)
print(f' --------------------------------------------\n {welcome}\n --------------------------------------------')

# Running input prompt
running = True
while (running==True):
    print()
    print("""Choose an option:
    
    1. Open a new bank account
    2. Access existing bank account
    3. Exit terminal
    """)
    
    # Build the menu selector
    choice = int(input("1, 2 or 3: "))

    # Build outer try statment to encapsulate the program
    try:
        # Selected if option 1: Open new bank account is chosen
        if choice == 1:
            print(f' \nTo create a new account, please provide the information below.\n ')
            client = Client(input("Name: "), str(input("Address: ")), str(input("Account Type (checking or savings): ")), float(input("Deposit amount: ")))
            response=bank.update_db(client)
            
            # Validate that account_number matches
            if (response==True):
                client_account = client.account['account_number']
                print(f'_______________________________________________________________\n<<Account created successfully! Your account number is: {client_account}>>')

        # Selected if option 2: Access existing bank account
        elif choice == 2:
            
            # Build inter try statement to access account and validate account_number
            try:
                print(f' \nTo access your account, please enter your access information.\n ')
                name = input("Name: ")
                account_number = int(input("Account number: "))
            except Exception:
                print("Your account number is a five digit number")

            current_client = bank.authentication(name, account_number)
            if current_client:
                print()
                print("Welcome {}!".format(current_client.account['name']))
                acc_open = True
                while (acc_open==True):
                    print()
                    print("""Choose an option:
        1. Withdraw
        2. Deposit
        3. Balance
        4. Exit Account Window
                        """)
                    acc_choice = int(input("1, 2, 3 or 4: "))
                    
                    # Selected if sub-option 1: Withdraw
                    if acc_choice == 1: 
                        print()
                        
                        # Add in exception handling for withdrawal issues
                        try:
                            withdraw = int(input("Withdraw amount: "))
                            if (withdraw <= 0):
                                raise Exception()                            
                            else:
                                current_client.withdraw(withdraw)
                        except Exception:
                            print("Your withdrawal amount should be a positive integer.")
                    
                    # Selected if sub-option 2: Deposit
                    elif acc_choice == 2: 
                        print()
                        
                        # Add in exception handling for withdrawal issues
                        try:
                            deposit = int(input("Deposit amount: "))
                            if (deposit <= 0):
                                raise Exception("")
                            else: 
                                current_client.deposit(deposit)
                        except Exception:
                            print("Your deposit amount should be a positive integer.")
                    
                    # Selected if sub-option 3: Balance
                    elif acc_choice == 3:  
                        print()
                        current_client.balance()
                    
                    # Selected if sub-option 4: Exit Account Window
                    elif acc_choice == 4:  
                        current_client = ''
                        acc_open = False    
                    else:
                        print("only entering 1,2, 3 and 4 is allowed")
            
            # Inner loop else statement if authentication fails
            else:
                print(f' \n-Authentication failed!\n-Reason: Account not found.\n----\nDo you want to try again? If not, ')
                continue

        # Selected if option 3: Exit the terminal
        elif choice == 3:
            running = False
        
        # Outer loop else to catch failures if anything is selected outside 1 through 3
        else:
            print("only entering 1,2 and 3 is allowed")
        
    # If anything breaks within the try statement (i.e. an individual tries to pass in a letter for an account number) run this general exception
    except Exception:
        print('-- We apologize for the inconvenience. --\n-- Due to security reasons suspicious activity has occured and we are terminating this session. --\nPlease try back at a later time.')
    
    # Do this no matter what happens within the program
    finally:
        print(f'==========================================\nThank you for allowing us to service you!\n==========================================')
```

Comment: A few tips for your code: (1) take a look at f-strings (2) define the texts in variables and use them in the functions to keep the logic separated from them and clean (easy to read) (3) export all logic to different functions to increase readability. For example in your case every choice can be a function called.

Comment: see edits in my answer. Please accept answer if your question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comments I would first check for the input:

```
if choice in ["1", "2", "3"]:
    do
else
    handle ...
```

same for the `balance` variable:

```
def validate_amount(a):
    try:
        return float(int(a*100))/100
    else:
        return False
```

something like that lets you check if `blance` is of type 12.34 for example.
Edit: Just saw some of your examples - for example for the names:

```
def validate_name(name):
    if not all(x.isalpha or x == "" for x in  name):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

also I would suggest upgrading to Python 3.8.

Edit on OPs request:

When creating big junks of code they become quite unreadable quick. I would shorten it by naming the strings and put them into the functions only by their variable names.

```
NL = "\n"
CREATE_ACC = f"To create a new account, please provide the information below."
```

using f-strings (careful - python 3.6+ needed!):

```
print(f"""Welcome {current_client.account['name']}!""")
```

Comment: @xltc I appreciate your pointers. I sat through this late last night and came up with a solution. Please see the solution attached: thank you.